# Каким образом передать на устройство по bluetooth одновременно аудио и текстовое сообщение?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Прошу подсказать. Имеется программа подобия радио-плеера на android, она воспроизводит звук (mp3, vaw) стриминговых сервисов icecast/shoutcast. При подключении к автомагнитоле по bluetooth звук есть, а название трека не передается. Каким образом осуществляется передача текстовой информации о проигрываемом треке одновременно с музыкой?

Comment: Укажите версии/модели телефона и магнитолы. Ваша проблема решается ковырянием в настройках того и другого, но где это зарыто, трудно сказать - надо искать.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Смартфон Samsung s10+, автомагнитола Volkswagen Composition Media. Собственно проблема не понятна тем, что аналогичные программы из плей маркета отображают название трека. Я думал, может что надо в манифесте указать еще, какие-то данные... или осуществлять как-то попутно передачу текстовой информации. В общем тайна, такой вопрос, на который решения однозначного нет нигде в интернете, все переискал. Буду благодарен за любую наводку.

Comment: передача информации о треке осуществляется в рамках протокола AVRCP.

Comment: Спасибо, это уже интересно. А не подскажете каким образом две разные программы передают практически одни и не же аудио потоки по блютуз и одна из них может не передавать название трека? Каким-то образом одна программа использует для передачи по блютуз AVRCP протокол, а другая иной?